# iPhone Apple Calendar

Tags: iphone

How do I remove the factory loaded Apple app known as "Calendar" from my iPhone 5?I have tried to remove this application by placing my finger on the application's icon. All app icons on the iPhone "jiggle" and display an "X" in the upper left hand corner of their icons.  When touching the "X" on any given app icon, the app then disappears, and is essentially removed from the iPhone's memory.   However,  the factory loaded Apple application named "Calendar" icon does not display an "X" in its upper left hand corner of its icon.  Therefore I can not remove the "Calendar" application.  Is there a procedure which will allow me to remove any factory loaded applications on my iPhone 5?

Answer (score 1):

Simply… 
You don't.

You cannot remove the base set of Apple apps - Calendar, Clock, Weather, Stocks, etc, etc.

Possibly Jailbreaking would allow you, but that's outside my knowledge-base.

The usual workaround for any undeletable app you don't want to see is put it on the last home screen, in a folder if you really need the screen-space